# why converted numpy array is NOT showing in the variable exloporer in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a dataframe called ff consisting of several columns, one of which is named "SMB". When I tried to convert this column to numpy array by `SMB=np.array(ff['SMB'])`, it went through but didn't show in the variable explorer. I am sure the SMB array has been created since I can call it out in the console.

However, when I changed the new array name to anything but SMB, e.g., `smb=np.array(ff['SMB'])`, it showed up in the variable explorer.

This might be a easy question, but for a beginner, I cannot get my head around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spyder does not show all-uppercase variables (they are actually *constants*, so you should not use all uppercase letters for variables). You can change this behavior through the configuration menu, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, such an easy problem drove me nuts. Appreciate your time and help.